# Parsing multi-dimensional json with Python issues

Tags: python, json, parsing, twitter

I'm working w/the twitter search API and using python to parse the data coming back. I'm a python-noob, so my error is probably my lack of understanding, though I'm stuck.

My response looks like this:

And my code; "responseJson" is a file that I've saved the response from twitter to for continued testing w/out hitting the API.

```
responseJson = json.loads(open(DEBUG_JSON).read())

for key, value in responseJson.iteritems():
if key == 'results':
    print "type: ", type(value)
    for tweetKey, tweetValue in value.iteritems():
        print tweetKey
```

When I execute the program, I get:

```
$ python search.py
type:  <type 'list'> <-- says it's a list!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "search.py", line 46, in <module>
for tweetKey, tweetValue in value.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

You can see the output says "value" is a list, which means I should be able to call iteritems() on it. I'm albe to call iteritems() on "responseJson just fine.

Any help / clarity is appreciated, TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iteritems()` can only be run on dicts and similar objects. JSON, when loaded, is a dict. In this case, responseJson is a dict, not a list.

Lists have no such method; you can iterate over them by default. You may want to doublecheck what `value` actually is. If it's a 2-element list you can just remove the `iteritems()`. Otherwise you'll have to investigate the structure more carefully.

Comment: type(value) seems to think it's a list - I will investigate further.

Comment: It may help to do `import pprint; pprint.pprint(responseJson)`. You'll be able to see exactly what you're working with.

Comment: Thanks - I got this working: results = responseJson['results']
    for tweet in results: